# Why does electron stop accelerating after passing anode in Cathode ray experiment?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, charge

This same question was posted on quora and what I found out there that there is some graphite coating around the anode extending to just before the florescent material. This graphite coating is connected to the anode. So they have the same potential.
Then the article states that this causes the electric field to be uniform there.
But I read somewhere (to be exact here - https://virtuelle-experimente.de/en/kanone/klassisch/funktion.php) that the velocity of electrons after passing anode stop accelerating and moves with constant velocity.
So my question is why? Why is field there 0

Answer (score 1):

As for acceleration one needs force, and here electric field supplies force to the emmiting electrons. Now Electric field is only present between anode and cathode thus electrons accelerate in their course of travelling between cathode to anode ,but after crossing anode there is noElectric field, means no force, thus it stops accelerating and moves with constant velocity after passing anode.

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that the anode potential is at ground potential as is the graphite coating which provides the return path for electrons.  The heated cathode from which the electrons are emitted is set at a negative voltage relative to the ground.  Thus once the electrons leave the vicinity of the electron gun they will travel at a constant velocity.

Comment: If there is a potential difference the electron must accelerate. I don't see why electron after leaving electron gun moves with constant velocity. Shouldn't it be accelerated towards the anode? And other sourrcres say that it moves with constant speed after passing through the anode.

Comment: Oh wait. Is this beacuse the electrodes will behave just like capacitors do. Both electrodes produces electric field which cancel out each other and thus gives 0 net electric field (outside the electrodes)

Comment: Yes, because the electron is travelling in a region of approximately zero electric field.